# wpa_supplicant disconnects with reason=3 on connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant

I am using a raspberry pi 4 to connect to my college network (so using WPA-Enterprise using PEAP) using `wpa_supplicant`

when I run the command,

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

with my `wpa_supplicant.conf` as follows:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
ap_scan=1
country=US
network={
        ssid="eduroam"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        eap=PEAP
        identity="example@example.edu"
        password=hash:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        phase1="peaplabel=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

everything seems good, no failed authentication, phase 1 and 2 completed, `CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED`. But then I get the following message:

```
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11 reason=3
```

It reconnects and goes through the whole process again, which seemingly repeats indefinitely. What is this `reason=3` and how do I fix it?

***PG69 EDIT***

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
 
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
# /etc/network/interfaces.d is an empty directory
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

wpa_supplicant assoc/auth log:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'eduroam'
wlan0: Associated with b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=3 subject='/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services' hash=d7a7a0fb5d7e2731d771e9484ebcdef71d5f0c3e0a2948782bc83ee0ea699ef4
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=3 subject='/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services' hash=d7a7a0fb5d7e2731d771e9484ebcdef71d5f0c3e0a2948782bc83ee0ea699ef4
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=2 subject='/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority' hash=68b9c761219a5b1f0131784474665db61bbdb109e00f05ca9f74244ee5f5f52b
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/ST=MI/L=Ann Arbor/O=Internet2/OU=InCommon/CN=InCommon RSA Server CA' hash=0a05c462756390dd1f1d5dd82794c300f04be789dce76d7e312f790d68fd385a
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/C=US/<address>/OU=EIT/CN=clearpass.XXX.edu' hash=74e40048dc2c07b1b5498b2792ceb62b976cc29d5c704d0426cedbccb49a8e31
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:clearpass.XXX.edu
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:clearpass-cra.XXX.edu
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:clearpass-hv.XXX.edu
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:clearpass-tel-2.XXX.edu
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:clearpass-tel.XXX.edu
EAP-MSCHAPV2: Authentication succeeded
EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11 reason=3
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'eduroam'
wlan0: Associated with b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b0:b8:67:ef:d9:11 reason=3
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'eduroam'
```

Not adding full wpa_supplicant debug log, >3200 lines. Pastebin link:

https://pastebin.com/Hx42FuwH

Comment: Could you please post the entire log where you see that event? Deauth reason codes and association status codes are standardized, but this is neither. Seeing how the log shows the client behaves might offer a clue.

Comment: Please show also /etc/network/interfaces or wicd config

Comment: After wading through wpa_supplicant's source code, 802.11 standard and similar I'm pretty certain what you are seeing _is_ actually an association problem. The config and log will help understand this better.

Comment: Ok I am not using any additional tools like wicd, but here is a pastebin for [the log](https://pastebin.com/eDnpLKH2), the [etc/network/interfaces](https://pastebin.com/VEL6P5YW), and also the [log with debug flag](https://pastebin.com/Hx42FuwH).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by reflashing my raspberry pi and making sure that before my `wpa_supplicant.conf` was set up I used `raspi-config` and set my WLAN country.